# My computer is likely blocking my access to an IP Address on my local network. What is the best way to troubleshoot the block?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, ip, malwarebytes

On my Win10 computer, I have Windows Defender and MalwareBytes running. Also on my network, I have a raspberry pi running octopi for my 3d printer. I can interact with octopi through a webpage which it posts on my local network.

I can access the webpage via the IP on my phone, connected to the same WiFi network. However, I cannot access the webpage or ping the IP from my computer. I'm guessing that something on my computer is blocking this IP.

I've added the IP as an "allowed" IP on MalwareBytes. Other than that, I'm not sure where to start as far as trying to get access to this IP on my computer. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you get it you do traceroute on the IP - perhaps it'll show the trace wanting to go "off-network"??  If you do arp -a from the windows - does the Mac address of the RasPI show up?

Comment: @MrR, the traceroute of the IP times out, and the results of arp -a does not show my RasPi

Comment: Can the win10 machine connect to any other computers on that network?  Does it actually get an IP address (if it's auto-configured?)?

Comment: Please add to your post the local IP addresses of all the devices you mentioned, including the router. Try temporarily to totally disable the MalwareBytes runtime protection.